# Jaspersoft page wrong orientation on print

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a jasper report to print a little invoice in portrait orientation, but whem I send to print, it's in landscape and takes up a lot of space at the A4 page.
How can I do to fix the orientation to maintain as portrait?

I've tryed to put the code of my jrxml here, but i'ts big, so, on the link you can download the .jxrml or by pastebin.

[invoice.jrxml](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AuzrEJzwNWacuz9CbfNGZzi6wXva)

[Invoice by pastebin](https://pastebin.com/pmiNpW75)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.5.1.final using JasperReports Library version 6.5.1  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="recibo" pageWidth="538" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="518" leftMargin="10" rightMargin="10" topMargin="10" bottomMargin="10" isIgnorePagination="true" uuid="11534e1c-358a-479d-bf93-b6f8c442b8f6">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="2.479338842975207"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="131"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit." value="cm"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.VerticalRowLayout"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.pageWidth" value="cm"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.topMargin" value="cm"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.bottomMargin" value="cm"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.leftMargin" value="cm"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.rightMargin" value="cm"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.columnWidth" value="cm"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.columnSpacing" value="cm"/>
    <parameter name="LOGO_EMITENTE" class="java.lang.Object" isForPrompting="false"/>
    <parameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="tit.identificacao" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="tit.valor" class="java.lang.Double"/>
    <field name="tit.valor_ext" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="pag.nome" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="tit.dtPag" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="emit.fant" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="emit.xNome" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="emit.xLgr" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="emit.nro" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="emit.xCpl" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="emit.xBairro" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="emit.cep" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="emit.xMun" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="emit.uf" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="emit.fone" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="emit.nrDocumento" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="emit.ie" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="emit.im" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="tit.dtPagExtenso" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="rec.nome" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <detail>
        <band height="180">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout"/>
            <frame>
                <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" x="0" y="0" width="518" height="180" uuid="c0e55f85-87e9-440d-ae9b-b3c4567027e5">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <box leftPadding="0" bottomPadding="0" rightPadding="0">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="121" y="9" width="270" height="20" uuid="1e5ac468-8b43-444b-9b66-fb0e81427f12">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Top">
                        <font fontName="Monospaced" size="14" isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[RECIBO]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement positionType="Float" x="80" y="32" width="435" height="20" uuid="dc2e375a-32f1-4ca7-8094-abcd3198af0e"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Top">
                        <font fontName="Monospaced" size="8" isBold="true" isUnderline="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{pag.nome}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField pattern="¤ #,##0.00;¤ -#,##0.00" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement positionType="Float" x="396" y="8" width="119" height="20" uuid="90210ce2-92ef-418d-bde0-8e9f5b675576"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Top">
                        <font fontName="Monospaced" size="12" isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{tit.valor}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" pattern="¤#,##0.00;¤-#,##0.00" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement positionType="Float" x="60" y="83" width="454" height="20" uuid="35a3c249-1a76-43ce-a290-eb754bee83af">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Top">
                        <font fontName="Monospaced" size="8" isBold="true" isUnderline="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{tit.identificacao}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement positionType="Float" x="459" y="172" width="52" height="8" uuid="7a716ed8-4f4e-44d4-a699-275510648c8a"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font fontName="Monospaced" size="5" isItalic="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[www.sentus.com.br]]></text>
                </staticText>
            </frame>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="2" y="32" width="78" height="12" uuid="19cd0546-23ff-4e55-b549-822b7a737b09"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Top">
                    <font fontName="Monospaced" size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Recebi(emos) de]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="2" y="52" width="58" height="12" uuid="88baf49a-023a-42ce-821e-7ef6bcd17b95"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Top">
                    <font fontName="Monospaced" size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[a quantia de]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" pattern="¤#,##0.00;¤-#,##0.00" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="60" y="52" width="455" height="24" uuid="ea680987-de0f-4766-89fc-f1fce0b2f47b">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Top">
                    <font fontName="Monospaced" size="8" isBold="true" isUnderline="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{tit.valor_ext}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="2" y="83" width="58" height="12" uuid="753a6211-5cf0-4bc8-a703-14a204e80e60">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Top">
                    <font fontName="Monospaced" size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[referente à]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="2" y="107" width="204" height="12" uuid="854cc28e-80fe-4fd2-9d55-0c5c9b850075"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Monospaced" size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[e para clareza firmo(amos) o presente.]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="153" y="130" width="220" height="12" uuid="c8231b66-f3f2-42b8-bcc0-7f6c29acfb58"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Monospaced" size="8" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{emit.xMun} + ", " + $F{tit.dtPagExtenso}]]></textFieldExpression>
                <patternExpression><![CDATA[$F{emit.xMun}]]></patternExpression>
            </textField>
            <line>
                <reportElement positionType="FixRelativeToBottom" x="193" y="158" width="149" height="1" uuid="4d95856f-f0ec-427d-bfc6-bc012da4f236"/>
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </line>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="163" y="170" width="204" height="10" uuid="a839d66e-220b-48e5-a15b-7021aac21b25"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Monospaced" size="7" isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Assinatura]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="163" y="160" width="204" height="10" uuid="3287959a-43aa-472d-8589-c1e777b8a146"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Top">
                    <font fontName="Monospaced" size="7" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{rec.nome}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Thank you

Comment: it works now. It would be a lot better, if you post it on pastebin.com this way no one has to download a file from an untrusted source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem creating a new report with the correct A4 size, and inside of it, I put my old report invoice.jrxml that I mentioned in the question.

It worked perfectly.

[invoice_A4.jrxml](https://pastebin.com/X0zHSMhq)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.5.1.final using JasperReports Library version 6.5.1  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="recibo_A4" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" whenResourceMissingType="Empty" uuid="97db2eb7-eacb-4a72-af21-544bfd5ffe59">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit." value="cm"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.pageHeight" value="cm"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.pageWidth" value="cm"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.topMargin" value="cm"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.bottomMargin" value="cm"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.leftMargin" value="cm"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.rightMargin" value="cm"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.columnWidth" value="cm"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.columnSpacing" value="cm"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="recibos" class="java.lang.Object"/>
    <detail>
        <band height="802" splitType="Stretch">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.VerticalRowLayout"/>
            <frame>
                <reportElement key="" x="0" y="0" width="555" height="802" uuid="7896b407-46da-4b1a-a3c7-835e45d14bc5">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.VerticalRowLayout"/>
                </reportElement>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <subreport>
                    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="555" height="802" uuid="ca317fd4-37db-4802-be56-943b67fd4189"/>
                    <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$F{recibos}]]></dataSourceExpression>
                    <subreportExpression><![CDATA["reports/recibo.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
                </subreport>
            </frame>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```